# Adobe Illustrator Layers are not going outside the main layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't believe I have to post such stuff! I saw a lot of tutorials on how to drag layers from the main layer, after applying release to layer sequence! But no way I can do that! I tried several times! and I did this many times :@

Why do AI Layers doing such misbehavior to me? :@

[image]

Comment: This is rather turning into a full tutorial series on "How do I operate my software?". That's not what Stack Exchange is for.

Comment: Illustrator Layers (and the panel) are *not the same* as Photoshop Layers (and the panel). See here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53704/turning-traced-and-expanded-image-back-to-single-layered-image-in-illustrator/53779#53779

Comment: Thank you @Scott. I have been feeling so helpless. I couldn't figure out what is happening. Working for 2 nights. Didn't sleep. I feel lost. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Illustrator a document has to have at least *one* layer and every object must be *inside* a layer.

So you can't move objects outside a layer and you can't delete the last layer.

Comment: Thank you so much.